# No se solucionar mis errores y no se hacer la parte b

Tags: c

Soy nuevo programando en C, si me podeis ayudar os lo agradeceria

Parte A: Dar de alta un nuevo cliente en el sistema. Inicialmente no existirán clientes registrados. El programa solicitará el nombre del fichero de texto que contiene la información del nuevo cliente. Se deberá mostrar un mensaje indicando si se ha dado de alta el cliente con éxito o ha habido algún error. Parte B: Eliminar un cliente. Para ello, el programa solicitará el DNI que se quiere eliminar. El programa informará de su eliminación y si no se localiza el DNI indicado con un error,.
Parte C: Listar datos. El programa listará el contenido del listado completo de clientes

MI codigo es este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <alloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LONG_DNI 9 
#define MAXLEN 200
typedef struct
{
 char *nombre;
 char *apellido;
 char nif[MAX_LONG_DNI];
 int edad;
} PERSONA;
PERSONA persona, *pPersona=NULL;
typedef enum { OK = 1, ERR = 0} status;
status LeerDatos(PERSONA *pp);
void MostrarDatos(PERSONA *);
int main(void)
{
 pPersona = &persona;
 if (LeerDatos(pPersona) == ERR)
 {
 LiberarPersona(pPersona);
 return ERR;
 }
 MostrarDatos(pPersona);
return OK;
}

status LeerDatos(PERSONA *pp)
{
 #define LONG_DNI 8 
 #define LONG_CADENA 100
 char temp[MAXLEN];
 int i;
 printf("Introduzca los datos de la persona:\n");
 printf("\nNombre: ");
 gets(temp);
 pp->nombre = (char *) malloc((strlen(temp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(pp->nombre, temp);
 fflush(stdout);
 printf("Apellido: ");
 gets(temp);
 pp->apellido = (char *) malloc((strlen(temp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
 if (CadenaVacia(temp) == OK)
 return ERR;
 else
 strcpy(pp->apellido, temp);
 for (i=0; i<strlen(pp->apellido); i++)
 {
 if (pp->apellido[i] == ' ')
 {
 printf("Introduzca un apellido");
 return ERR;
 }
 }
 printf("Introduzca el DNI ");
 gets(temp);
 if (strlen(temp) != LONG_DNI)
 {
 printf("El DNI debe tener 8 digitos.\n");
 return ERR;
 }
return OK;
}

void MostrarDatos(PERSONA *pp)
{
 printf("\nLos datos obtenidos son:\n");
 printf("\nNombre: %s", pp->nombre);
 printf("\nApellido: %s", pp->apellido);
printf("\nDNI: %s", pp->dni);
}
```

Me da error aqui:

```
 printf("Introduzca el DNI ");
```

[Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

y en esta parte del codigo:

```
 return ERR;
 }
 }
 printf("Introduzca el DNI ");
 gets(temp);
 if (strlen(temp) != LONG_DNI)
 {
 printf("El DNI debe tener 8 digitos.\n");
 return ERR;
 }
return OK;
}

[Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
[Error] expected unqualified-id before 'if'
[Error] expected unqualified-id before 'return'
[Error] expected declaration before '}' token
```

NO se hacer la parte b de eliminar a una persona con el dni

Comment: Por favor, no crees preguntas nuevas. Si te han cerrado una pregunta lo que tienes que hacer es editarla para que sea conforme a las reglas del sitio. Entonces abriremos de nuevo tu pregunta y empezarás a tener respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Lo que veo es que falta cerrar llaves en donde se encuentra el if donde validas la cadena vacia, ya que lo tienes de la siguiente forma:

```
status LeerDatos(PERSONA *pp){
    char temp[MAXLEN];
    int i;
    printf("Introduzca los datos de la persona:\n");
    printf("\nNombre: ");
    gets(temp);
    pp->nombre = (char *) malloc((strlen(temp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(pp->nombre, temp);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("Apellido: ");
    gets(temp);
    pp->apellido = (char *) malloc((strlen(temp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    
    // aqui es donde no cierras la validacion
    if (CadenaVacia(temp) == OK) 
        return ERR;
    else
        strcpy(pp->apellido, temp);
        for (i=0; i<strlen(pp->apellido); i++){
            if (pp->apellido[i] == ' '){
                printf("Introduzca un apellido");
                return ERR;
            }
        }
        printf("Introduzca el DNI ");
        gets(temp);
        if (strlen(temp) != LONG_DNI){
            printf("El DNI debe tener 8 digitos.\n");
            return ERR;
        }
        return OK;
}
```

por ende lanza los errores ya que no lo compila correctamente.